# Search forward for the [count]'th occurrence of the text selected in visual mode

Tags: vim

I want to search, like I do with the `*` command, for a pattern I have selected in visual mode.

I am aware of visual mode yanking, which fills the register `0` by default, and the possibility of just searching by `/` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (retrieving) the contents of register `0` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd>) to paste the pattern as a search.

Thing is, I do not want to YANK first, I already have something yanked, I just want to search for what's selected in visual mode now.

How can I do that, please? Can I do that without fiddling with different "yank to register N" tricks?

Comment: Are you talking about highlighted or selected text in visual mode? It seems like you want to use selection, but wrote the word "highlighted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution that works for me to make `*` work with `[count]` in visual mode:

```
vnoremap * :call <SID>VisualSearch()<cr>:set hls<cr>
fun! s:VisualSearch() range
   let unnamed = @"
   let repeat = v:count
   exe 'norm gv"zy' | let @/ = @z
   for x in range(repeat)
      call search(@/, 'ws')
   endfor
   let @" = unnamed
endfun
```

You change the "z"s on line five to whatever registers you never use.

Comment: Unfortunately, yanking to a named register still clobbers the unnamed register.

Comment: True... you could set it and replace it. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use gvim or console vim built with X support (check if `'guioption'` is available) and `a` is present in your `'guioptions'`, then you can get current selection from `*` register. Otherwise, I'm afraid there is no easy way to do that without writing a VimL function, which will extract the selection based on values of `<` and `>` marks. That function then can be used with `CTRL-R =` in the search prompt.

Comment: I am not using Vim in GUI mode most of the time.

Comment: @Robottinosino check if you can set `'guioptions'` in console vim, this depends on the build. If this option is available, then the trick will work for you in console vim too.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just combine all the steps you've outlined into a mapping? The only thing missing is saving and restoring the unnamed register, and a little bit of escaping.

```
" Atom \V sets following pattern to "very nomagic", i.e. only the backslash has special meaning.
" As a search pattern we insert an expression (= register) that
" calls the 'escape()' function on the unnamed register content '@@',
" and escapes the backslash and the character that still has a special
" meaning in the search command (/|?, respectively).
" This works well even with <Tab> (no need to change ^I into \t),
" but not with a linebreak, which must be changed from ^M to \n.
" This is done with the substitute() function.
" gV avoids automatic reselection of the Visual area in select mode.

vnoremap <silent> * :<C-U>let save_unnamedregister=@@<CR>gvy/\V<C-R><C-R>=substitute(escape(@@,'/\'),"\n",'\\n','ge')<CR><CR>:let @@=save_unnamedregister<Bar>unlet save_unnamedregister<CR>gV
```